# Rectangle collision detection in Arrays in Processing

Tags: arrays, processing, collision

so I'm a very new programmer and I'm trying to figure out how to get rectangles in an array to detect collision. I tried to think it out and found some examples that I thought would work, but so far has not.

Here's my code, it's not very much.

I get the message sometimes when the boxes are towards the top of the screen, but am not sure why.

```
Box [] b = new Box[1];

float x,y,w,h;

void setup(){
  size(800,800);
  x=random(width);
  y=random(height);
  w=random(200);
  h=random(200);


  b[0] =  new Box(x,y,w,h);

}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  x=random(width);
  y=random(height);
  w=25;
  h=25;

  for(int j = 0; j<b.length;j++){
    for(int k = 0; k<b.length;k++){
      if(j!=k){
        b[j].contact(b[k]);

      }


    }

  }

  for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
    b[i].run();


  }



}


void keyPressed(){

  if(key =='n'){

    Box boxnew = new Box(x,y,w,h);
    b = (Box[]) append(b,boxnew);



  }


}


class Box{

  float x,y,w,h,c1,c2,c3,ii,xmo,ymo;

 Box(float mx,float my,float mw,float mh){

   x=mx;
   y=my;
   w=mw;
   h=mh;
   c1=150;
   c2=50;
   c3=200;
   xmo=1;
   ymo=1;


 } 
  void run(){
    maker();
    mover();
    wcolli();


  }

  void maker(){
    ii=random(-1,1);
    c1+=ii;
    c2+=ii;
    c3+=ii;
    fill(c1,c2,c3);
    rect(x,y,w,h);

  }

  void mover(){
    x+=xmo;
    y+=ymo;


  }

  void wcolli(){

    if(x>800-w||x<1){
        xmo*=-1;
      }
      if(y>800-h||y<1){
        ymo*=-1;
      }


  }
  void contact(Box b){

    if((b.x>=this.x&&b.x<=this.w||b.w>=this.x&&b.w<=this.x) && (b.h>=this.y||b.y<=this.h)){
      println("hit");



    }
    if((b.y<=this.h&&b.y>=this.y||b.h<=this.h&&b.h>=this.y) && (b.x<=this.w||b.w>=this.x)){
      println("hit");


    }


  }
}
```

Comment: Question related..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774684/android-rect-intersect-is-always-false/23775232#23775232

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems in your collision detection. The most significant is that you're trying to use the width and height (`w` and `h`) as though they are absolute positions. They're actually relative to the top-left corners of each box, so that's why things don't seem to be working. You have to calculate the actual bottom-right corner positions before doing any comparisons.

You also have to be quite careful with your `if` conditions. It's best to use brackets to clarify the precedence of logical operations when you're combining AND with OR (`&&` and `||`) etc.

For simple axis-aligned rectangle collisions like this, here's an approach I find useful:

```java
void contact(Box b) {

    // Calculate the bottom-right corners of the boxes.
    float myX2 = x + w;
    float myY2 = y + h;
    float otherX2 = b.x + b.w;
    float otherY2 = b.y + b.h;

    // If this box is entirely to the left of box b, then there is no collision.  
    if (x < b.x && myX2 < b.x) return;

    // If this box is entirely to the right of box b, then there is no collision.
    if (x > otherX2 && myX2 > otherX2) return;

    // If this box is entirely above box b, then there is no collision.
    if (y < b.y && myY2 < b.y) return;

    // If this box is entirely below box b, then there is no collision.
    if (y > otherY2 && myY2 > otherY2) return;

    // If we reach this point, the boxes haven't missed each other.
    // Therefore, there must be a collision.
    println("hit");

}
```

That's determining a collision by checking for every possible situation in which one box could miss another. If it determines that they haven't missed each other, then logically there must be a collision.