# android Rect.intersect is always false

Tags: java, android

Soldier Class

```
    centerX += speedX;
     r.set(centerX , centerY, 50, 50);
```

Bullet Class

```
   centerX += speedX;
    r.set(centerX, centerY, 50, 50);
    if(Rect.intersects(r,GameScreen.soldier.r))
    {
        System.out.println("collision");

    }
```

I'm having trouble with collision detection.  I have tried Rect.intersects, r.intersect(r1), r.contains(r1) and always false.  Im even drawing the rectangles to make sure they are drawn correctly and they are but collision is always false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Check if two rectangles collide
 * x_1, y_1, width_1, and height_1 define the boundaries of the first rectangle
 * x_2, y_2, width_2, and height_2 define the boundaries of the second rectangle
 */
boolean rectangle_collision(float x_1, float y_1, float width_1, float height_1, float x_2, float y_2, float width_2, float height_2)
{
  return !(x_1 > x_2+width_2 || x_1+width_1 < x_2 || y_1 > y_2+height_2 || y_1+height_1 < y_2);
}
```